# How i can get the current selected fragment id in navigation graph while i'm using two graphs

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two navigation graphs in my project one is drawerfragment graph and other is for other fragments navigation graph i want to get id of the selected graph from drawer and from other fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Your project have only one activity then below code work fine.
You have to implement destinationchanged listener to your navController like below.

First find your navController using below code

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this@MainActivity, R.id.navHostFragment)
```

now attach destination changed listener to your navcontroller like

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
            destinationId = destination.id
        }
```

`destinationId` this is your fragment id.

and other navigation graph for your side-menu drawer then do same code into your drawer fragment which contain `NavigationView`.

Comment: This is correct when you a one activity it helped me out thanks

Comment: for more you can check https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events